Как подключать различные библиотеки (WinAPI, SFML, Crypto++) в VS Code?
Если в VS можно что-то подключить, то тут такое не возможно. На ютубе тоже нет гайдов, все только на VS. Мне на VS  переходить, или же есть способ подключать?

Конечно все можно подключить. Фишка в том, что VSC просто запускает консольные команды для сборки, поэтому нужно разбираться как собирать программы с библиотеками просто в консоли, а потом те же самые команды ввести в VSC. (А вы не сказали, какой у вас компилятор и какую библиотеку пытаетесь подключить, поэтому чем помочь - непонятно.)

Странно то, что ответ загуглился за минуту.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference
А вообще да, перейти на студию или clion был-бы более логичный вариант. Сам пользуюсь clion уже лет 5 и он полюбился всем Си программистам в нашем офисе.

"загуглился за минуту" Ну такое. Эти настройки влияют только на подсказки в коде, а не на саму компиляцию.

@HolyBlackCat Ааа, ты имел ввиду компиляцию. Ну, честно говоря я не видел ни одного знакомого программиста который бы хорошо отзывался об NMAKE от Microsoft. Это очень отвратительная тулза с морем подводных камней.  Практический все используют сторонний софт для компиляции под винду.

??? Никто ничего не говорил про nmake. "ты имел ввиду компиляцию" Где?

Я имел ввиду компиляцию проектов под MSVCPP, из коробки с компилятором прилетает NMAKE. Его никто не любит. Я на работе пользуюсь классическим MAKE, у нас в офисе очень много реально старых Cи программистов, им написать макросы под старый MAKE раз плюнуть. Для своих пэт проектов я использую CMAKE. Но это реально сколько людей, столько мнений. Если спросить у людей на чём лучше собирать C, C++ проекты. Всё упрётся в холивар.
ps: Опять-же я с старым MSCPP давно не работал, на работе стак - Java+Си, для себя - Go или "D"

Окей, но автор-то пользуется VSC, не VS.

@HolyBlackCat у меня конец рабочего дня, видимо заработался и не понял вопроса в комментарии.

Странные вы вещи пишите. Nmake помнят разве что динозавры, работавшие году в 1998 с Visual Studio 6. Собственно в составе инструментов его держат для поддержки на плаву легаси софта 20 летней выдержки. И непонятно, с чего бы отзываться о nmake плохо, в целом повторяет функционал make, при этом синтаксис содержит чуть меньше крякозябр.
